# Laravel how to pass data from controller to blade

Tags: laravel

I'm building a Laravel site. I want submitted form data to run a query and the results to be inserted into a table format. I am using oracle DB and I have connected it to Laravel. Also, I have created the form, and the query gives the results right. What I can't do is to pass results into the table successfully.

My files are the following:

1. Routes.php (or web.php for newer laravel versions):

   The search.blade.php (which is the form with the post method)

   -->
           User Data Entry
       
       
           Input Data
   -->
          Input Data

   ```
       <form method="post" action="/dedomena" id="forma">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
           <fieldset>
               <legend>Insert</legend>
               Registration Number:<br>
               <input type="number" name="AM" min="1000000" max="9999999"><br>
               <input type="submit" value="Search">
           </fieldset>
       </form>
   </body>
   ```

   My controller (NewController.php) runs the query. The results are displayed correctly but in a list format. I want to put them in a table format.

   get('AM');
            echo('Results for student with registration number: ');
            echo($myVar);
            $entries = DB::table('SCC_ANSWER')->where('AM', $myVar)->get();
            dd($entries);
        }
    }

I want to be passed at another blade called pinakas.blade.php which should look like the following. How can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>AM</th>
                <th>ST</th>
                <th>CS</th>
                <th>REGYEAR</th>
                <th>REGTERMIN</th>
                <th>CSYEAR</th>
                <th>REGTYPE</th>
                <th>REGDESCR</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
                <th>STGROUP</th>
                <th>SEM1</th>
                <th>SEM2</th>
                <th>SEM3</th>
                <th>SEM4</th>
                <th>SEM5</th>
                <th>SEM6</th>
                <th>SEM7</th>
                <th>SEM8</th>
                <th>SEM9</th>
                <th>SEM10</th>
                <th>SEM11</th>
                <th>SEM12</th>
                <th>SEM1B</th>
                <th>SEM2B</th>
                <th>SEM3B</th>
                <th>SEM4B</th>
                <th>SEM5B</th>
                <th>SEM6B</th>
                <th>SEM7B</th>
                <th>SEM8B</th>
                <th>SEM9B</th>
                <th>SEM10B</th>
                <th>SEM11B</th>
                <th>SEM12B</th>
                <th>SEM1P</th>
                <th>SEM2P</th>
                <th>SEM3P</th>
                <th>SEM4P</th>
                <th>SEM5P</th>
                <th>SEM6P</th>
                <th>SEM7P</th>
                <th>SEM8P</th>
                <th>SEM9P</th>
                <th>SEM10P</th>
                <th>SEM11P</th>
                <th>SEM12P</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
                <th>TOTALB</th>
                <th>TOTALP</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               // <td><?php $entries?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: database is ok. It works fine and the query gives the results. I don't know how to pass data from controller to blade. $entries must go to pinakas.blade and inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your tips. The problem was the capital letters I was using in the blade! I will add below the excerpts in case someone else has relevant problem in future projects:

1) Routes.php (or web.php for newer laravel versions):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


Route::get('/search', 'PagesController@search'); //find student data!
Route::post('/dedomena', 'NewController@psaxe');
```

2) Search.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form_style.css">  -->
    <title>Εισαγωγή Δεδομένων Χρήστη</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--
<k1 class = "myhome">Εισαγωγή Δεδομένων</k1>
-->
Εισαγωγή Δεδομένων

<form method="post" action="/dedomena" id="forma">

  {{csrf_field()}}

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Εισαγωγή</legend>

        Αριθμός Μητρώου:<br>
        <input type="number" name="AM" min="1000000" max="9999999"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση">
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

3) Controller (NewController.php)

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;


class NewController extends Controller


{



    public function psaxe(Request $request)
    {

        $myVar = $request->get('AM');
        echo('Αποτελέσματα για τον φοιτητή με ΑΜ: ');
        echo($myVar);
        $entries = DB::table('SCC_ANSWER')->where('AM', $myVar)->get();
       // dd($entries);

        return view('pinakas', ['entries1' => $entries]);


    }}
```

4) The blade (pinakas.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Αποτελέσματα</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>AM</th>
        <th>ST</th>
        <th>CS</th>
        <th>REGYEAR</th>
        <th>REGTERMIN</th>
        <th>CSYEAR</th>
        <th>REGTYPE</th>
        <th>REGDESCR</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>STGROUP</th>
        <th>SEM1</th>
        <th>SEM2</th>
        <th>SEM3</th>
        <th>SEM4</th>
        <th>SEM5</th>
        <th>SEM6</th>
        <th>SEM7</th>
        <th>SEM8</th>
        <th>SEM9</th>
        <th>SEM10</th>
        <th>SEM11</th>
        <th>SEM12</th>
        <th>SEM1B</th>
        <th>SEM2B</th>
        <th>SEM3B</th>
        <th>SEM4B</th>
        <th>SEM5B</th>
        <th>SEM6B</th>
        <th>SEM7B</th>
        <th>SEM8B</th>
        <th>SEM9B</th>
        <th>SEM10B</th>
        <th>SEM11B</th>
        <th>SEM12B</th>
        <th>SEM1P</th>
        <th>SEM2P</th>
        <th>SEM3P</th>
        <th>SEM4P</th>
        <th>SEM5P</th>
        <th>SEM6P</th>
        <th>SEM7P</th>
        <th>SEM8P</th>
        <th>SEM9P</th>
        <th>SEM10P</th>
        <th>SEM11P</th>
        <th>SEM12P</th>
        <th>TOTAL</th>
        <th>TOTALB</th>
        <th>TOTALP</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($entries1 as $entry)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $entry->am }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->st }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->cs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->regyear }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->regtermin }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->csyear }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->regtype }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->regdescr }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->stgroup }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem5 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem6 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem7 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem8 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem9 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem10 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem11 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem12 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem1b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem2b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem3b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem4b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem5b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem6b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem7b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem8b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem9b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem10b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem11b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem12b }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem1p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem2p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem3p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem4p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem5p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem6p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem7p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem8p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem9p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem10p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem11p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->sem12p }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->total }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->totalb }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entry->totalp }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

5) And the PagesController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;  //sos:: needed only for function emfanisi!!!!
use DB;                       //sos:: needed only for function emfanisi!!!!


class PagesController extends Controller
{




    public function search()
    {
        return view('search');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public function psaxe(Request $request) {
    $myVar=$request->get('AM');
    $entries=DB::table('SCC_ANSWER')->where('AM',$myVar)->get();
    return view('view_file_location')->with('entries' => $entries);
}
```

//$entries can be use in blade page

Comment: Unfortunately variable does not pass to blade.

Comment: @Konstantinos Can you try this.  `return view('view_file_location', $entries);`

Comment: This gives me again Undefined variable: entries1 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\pinakas.blade.php)

Comment: We are passing `$entries` not `$entries1`, if it is not usefull, please remove or change to `$entries`.

Comment: I have the complete solution below! I fixed it.

Comment: If my answer is helpfule, Please accept and upvoted my answer, because helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the data into the blade view this is the better Approach.

```
$entries = DB::table('SCC_ANSWER')->where('AM', $myVar)->get();


return view('foldername.viewName',compact('entries'));
```

In the Blade View

```
 @if(!empty($entries))


                        @foreach($entries as $entry)

                                 <tr class="warning" >
                                    <td >{{ $entry->AM}}</td>
                                    <td >{{ $entry->ST}}</td>
                                    <td >{{ $entry->CS}}</td>
                                    <td >{{ $entry->REGYEAR}}</td>
                                    <td >{{ $entry->role_name }}</td>
                                    <td >{{ $entry->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td ></td>
                                     .............
                                </tr>

                                @endforeach

                       @endif
```

Comment: I did it as you suggested (<td >{{ $entry->AM}}</td>, etc ) for all table fields but it does not work . I get an error Undefined property: stdClass::$AM (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\pinakas.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('path.to.your.view', compact('entries'));
```

in Your view you just do this:

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
<tr>
...
```

Etc.

Comment: But what didn't work then? Could you share a error message? The only reason why this wouldn't work is whenever the data isn't formatted as a Collection or Array.

Comment: I should update the pinakas.blade because it couldn't be populated and also to use lowercase in assignments. I did not know it was case sensitive.. . . Below you can see the solution on the whole. I tested it and it works and I put it in case someone has the same problems in the future. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your results with `@foreach`:

```php
<tr>
    @foreach($entries as $entry)
        <td>{{ $entry->am }}</td>
        <td>{{ $entry->st }}</td>
        <td>{{ $entry->cs }}</td>
        <td>....</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

Comment: If I do so I get this error: Undefined property: stdClass::$AM (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\pinakas.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

`return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);`

When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as  `<?php echo $key; ?>`. As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the with method to add individual pieces of data to the view